# Getting an error in unity Assets/scripts/LearningHowToProgram.cs(7,13): error CS1001: Identifier expected

Tags: c#, macos, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class LearningHowToProgram : MonoBehaviour
{


int c = 12 + 13; 
sum_of_2_numbers(c); 
void sum_of_2_numbers(int a)
    {
        print( a ); 
    }

}
```

I was trying to get into game development and I learnt about functions recently and when I tried to use them I got an error saying this:

> Assets/scripts/LearningHowToProgram.cs(7,13): error CS1001: Identifier expected

I don't know what triggered to show this but it was coming up on console in Unity.

Comment: try public static void sum_of_2_numbers(int a)

Comment: `int c = 12 + 13; sum_of_2_numbers(c);` needs to be inside a function.

Comment: This is also not summing 2 numbers. You summed them when you made your variable c. Just so you understand

Answer (score 0):

The console error pretty clearly states the line the issue is coming from and your IDE will give you a hint what is wrong here.
This is fundamental to understanding your own code.

In this instance it is your line:

```
sum_of_2_numbers(c);
```

You cannot call methods like this from the body of you class.
In a Unity context you would call them from one of the Unity events like `Start()`

Therefore it is interpreted as you defining something which is incomplete.

Also as others have mentioned your method would not actually sum 2 number only print the value of c.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class LearningHowToProgram : MonoBehaviour
{


    private void Start()
    {
        sum_of_2_numbers(12, 13);
    }

    private void sum_of_2_numbers(int a, int b)
    {
        int mySum = a + b;
        print(mySum);
    }

}
```

The name of your method `sum_of_2_numbers` also does not follow C# naming conventions and should probably be renamed to "SummarizeTwoNumbers"